# The state of radiobutton is not stable in LWC. I have created a timer function, when the timer function is over then the value is getting fixed

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

html part

```html
<template for:each={wrongAndRightAns} for:item="answer">
    <div class="grid-item" key={answer.key}>
        <label><input type="radio" name="itemSelection" value={answer.name} oninput={handleRadioChange} checked={isNotChecked} />{answer.name}</label>
     </div>
</template>
```

js part

```js
    handleRadioChange(event) {
        try {
            if (event && event.target && event.target.type === 'radio') {
                this.printname = event.target.value;
                this.selectAns = this.printname;
            }else{
                console.error('Event is undefined.');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error1144',err.message);
        }
    }
    timer() {
        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.countDownTimer--;
            if (this.countDownTimer <= 0) {
                clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);
                //this.navigateToEndTemplate();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        if (this.countDownInterval) {
            clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);
        }
    }
```

*more part*

```
    nextQuestion() {
        try {
            this.callAPI();
            this.shuffleArrayAndSetupWAR();
            //if(this.isNotChecked){this.isNotChecked=false;}
            //this.resetRadio();
            this.handleRadioChange();
            this.selectedAnswers.push(this.selectAns);
            console.log(this.selectAns);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedAnswers));
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.error('Error11', err.message);
        }
    }

I have radiobuttons in html, when I am pressing a button it is not getting selected and again and again getting deselected only after when the 60 second timer is over then the value is stable. I think the issue is in some hooks, but I am not sure how to rectify it. Can please someone help me on this one. If anything else is needed please let me know. Thanks


@track isNotChecked=false;
is passed as property and in html
    resetRadio(){
        this.isNotChecked=false;
    }
I have tried passing the function and direct logic also to clear the selected the radiobutton. I have a nextQuestion button in that I am again calling the api to populate the data to generate next values for radiobutton. Hope it gives you some clear image.
image for reference.
![reference](https://i.imgur.com/FHWBAKi.png)
```

Comment: In summary, `checked={is}` is the direct cause of the problem. However, we don't have enough code to prescribe a complete answer. Please [edit] your question so we can help you properly. It's better to have too much code than too little.